# emulate usb port

Tags: usb, emulation

How can I emulate an USB port in Windows? What I try to do is to tell
Windows that my program is an USB slave.

A good example is the FrizBox USB-Remoteconnection which can let an USB printer from the friz box looks like a printer at the usb port of the pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you have to write a device driver for windows. It should be printer device driver - so it would emulate printer device. If you want to be class independent (eg memory stick and so on) you probably have to write more device drivers.